# how to check if MKL is installed and find its path

Tags: software-installation, directory, path

Please help me out. it has been 3 hours that I am trying to install OSQP.

I needed to install MKL. I downloaded the full package and installed it. but I don't know where is it and how I can check if it is alright.
from here:

https://osqp.org/docs/get_started/linear_system_solvers.html

I need to do this:

```
  source $MKLROOT/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

where MKLROOT is the MKL installation directory. but what is that?

I would greatly appreciate If you help me

Comment: naghmehs-MacBook-Pro:~ naghmeh$  source $MKLROOT/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
-bash: /bin/mklvars.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah... I guess that's not the case then. Sorry.

Comment: What steps did you take to install the package? Please edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the MKLROOT is wherever you installed MKL.   On my machine it is in `/opt/intel/mkl/`, but yours may be different.    Information about the default install directories for MKL on various OSs can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-111-install-guide).

You also do not need MKL to use OSQP.   If you are using cmake to build OSQP directly then you can specify `-DENABLE_MKL_PARDISO=FALSE`, in which case OSQP will just use only its own linear solver `qdldl`.